# Where to put a Crawler script in Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, web-crawler

I have created a really simple PHP crawler, which I want to implement in a Laravel project. I don't know where to put it tho.. I want to start the script and just run it while the application is up.

I know that it should not be in the Controllers, or in the Cron schedule, so any suggestions where to set it up?

```
$homepage = 'https://example.com';
$already_crawled = [];
$crawling = [];


function follow_links($url){
  global $already_crawled;
  global $crawling;

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

  $linklist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

  foreach ($linklist as $link) {
    $l = $link->getAttribute("href");
    $full_link = 'https://example.com'.$l;

    if (!in_array($full_link, $already_crawled)) {
      $already_crawled[] = $full_link;
      $crawling[] = $full_link;
      echo $full_link.PHP_EOL;
      // Insert data in the DB
    }
  }

  array_shift($crawling);
  foreach ($crawling as $link) {
    follow_links($link);
  }
}

follow_links($homepage);
```

Comment: Actually this is not good idea. Bcoz laravel is specially designed for build awesome MVC application. If you want to inject/connect some `PHP Scripts` like `crawler` or `spider` or `bulk mailer` `Etc...` Please seperate those files and call as another `thread` or  `CRON JOB`. Do not merge those jobs with App.

Comment: So it should not be part of the Laravel application, but a separate app running on the server? If so, how can I "let it fly" without canceling it? At the moment when I start the script from the terminal, it is all good until I decide to make another command..

Comment: You can use command nohup with & "nohup php path_to_script.php &". & - make it background, nohup - prevents script execution stoping after you close terminal connection.

Comment: And if for some reason I want to stop the scrip, how can I do is?

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar That's really bad advice. Laravel is fully capable of this sort of thing, and there are **major** benefits from doing it all in Laravel - you get its caching, database, queue, logging, etc. all built-in by doing so.

Comment: @ceejayoz I already done those stuffs in laravel 5.6 ... But server went down. Then a software engineer said me seperate those larger scripts. Then it was walking fine without any interruption. Crawlers, Spiders, Mining algo and other huge scripts should run on seperate server. If your server powerful then run on seperate thread (Do Not Overload). Or do some parallel programming (Recommened for mining process).

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab Deploy as a service. Start / Terminate when you want. Consider your server performance.....

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a combination of a [Service](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container) class, [Command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#writing-commands), and possibly [Jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#creating-jobs) — and then running them from [worker processes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#running-the-queue-worker).

Your Service would be a class which contains all of the logic for crawling a page. The crawler service is then used either by an artisan command, a queued job, or a combination of both.

You are right that you don't want to run the crawler *directly* from the built-in Laravel scheduler (because it might run for a long time and prevent other scheduled tasks from running). However, one option is to use your Laravel schedule to run a task which checks for urls that need to be re-crawled and dispatches queued *jobs* to your *worker processes*,  which are very easy to implement in Laravel.

Each new discovered url can be thought of as a separate task and queued individually for crawling, rather than running the process "continually" while the application is online.

Comment: This is an awesome suggestion, but I feel pretty lost with all of the "terms" thrown here. :D Can you point me to a tutorial or something similar to what you just told me? I can add the script I created in my question if it will be any help, thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I included links to a number of documentation pages on Laravel's website, so I would recommend starting with those and googling unfamiliar terms as needed. Laracasts is also a good resource for a lot of things relating to Laravel, and programming in general. There's obviously a limit to the scope of what I can answer in a Stackoverflow post, but this series includes some of those concepts as well: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab a quick google search also shows that there are even a number of crawler packages available for Laravel, as well as blog posts that cover implementing crawlers for Laravel.

Comment: I saw most of the packages, but I was soo lost. I was able to make the above function in PHP, and this will work for me, but as I've said before, I need to implement it with the Laravel project. Thank you for the links, I will check them out! :)